# Show a form on Workbook_New

Tags: excel, vba

I want to show a userform when the user creates a new Excel workbook. For this purpose I have the skeleton code below in a class module. It gives me a number of headaches.

```
Option Explicit

    Dim IsNewWb As Boolean

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ' 09 Feb 2018
    Set App = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    ' 13 Feb 2018

    If IsNewWb Then ShowDocSpecs
    IsNewWb = True
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    ' 13 Feb 2018

    If Len(Wb.Path) = 0 Then
        ShowDocSpecs
        IsNewWb = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ShowDocSpecs()
    ' 10 Feb 2018

    Dim FrmSpecs As DocSpecs

'    Set FrmSpecs = New DocSpecs
    MsgBox "Show WbSpecs"
End Sub
```

The first problem is that I don't want the form to show when Excel starts up. The Boolean `IsNewWb` is supposed to prevent that, and it does. However, when I open Excel, then open another workbook and then close that other book the empty workbook first created becomes the ActiveWorkbook and the New event fires, in essence for the second time for the same workbook but this time not suppressed. I thought of testing if the workbook is empty (CountA = 0) and possibly check the `Saved` property. Also that workbook has no path. Too many choices. I think I will close the blank workbook when the user opens another. Perhaps you know a better way?

Second problem is that when the user creates a new workbook using a template the New event doesn't seem to occur. Instead the Open event occurs. The above code already reflects that.

Now I found a third problem which is that the New event occurs when a workbook first opened in protected mode is enabled. How can I identify such a workbook? Usually I receive such workbooks as email attachments (that is where I found the discrepancy). I would like advice on how to identify the event which occurs when the workbook is enabled (the one that triggers the New event). Can someone tell me how to identify a workbook as open in protected mode and, for testing purposes, how to return a workbook which has been enabled to the status which causes Excel to open it in protected mode. How can I prevent the New event from showing the form under this condition?

All of the above seems terribly complicated for what appears a very simple demand. Is there a much better, completely different way of approaching the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's (2010) New event only occurs when a new workbook is created from scratch. It does not occur when a new workbook is created from a template or from another workbook.

Excel creates a new workbook from scratch when  it first starts and, if no other workbook is open at the time, before it quits. My aim was to show a user form only when the user intentionally creates a new workbook by whatever means. Therefore the code had to prevent the form from being shown whenever it came into Excel's own mind to create a new workbook. The code below does that.

However, I also wanted the form to be shown when the user created a new workbook from a template or another workbook. In that case Excel's WorkbookOpen even fires. The task therefore shifted from reacting to the creation of a new workbook to preventing a reaction if the workbook wasn't new by my definition.

New workbooks created from a template don't have a `Path` although they do have a `FileFormat`. Workbooks received by email and opened directly from Outlook without first being saved don't have a `FileFormat`. This enables distinction between a "new" workbook created from a template and never saved and an "old" workbook received by email. Note that the email attachment would open in protected mode if it has a VBA project and the open event fires only after editing has been enabled.

Here is the entire code, including the Debug.Prints I used for testing. This code is in the class module `XlEvents` in an add-in which loads with Excel and is initialised in a `Workbook_Open` procedure in the xlam.

```
    Option Explicit

    Private WithEvents App As Application
    Dim IsNewWb As Boolean

' Peculiarities ============================================

  ' WorkbookOpen fires instead of NewWorkbook when a Wb is newly
  ' created from a template or other Wb.
  ' A new Wb such created has no path.

  ' The Open event for a Wb opened in protected mode will not occur
  ' until the Enable button is pressed.
  ' At that moment the Wb has no FileFormat.

  ' When Excel is closed while Workbooks.Count = 0 a new, blank
  ' Wb is created before quitting, causing the New event to occur.

' ==========================================================

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ' 09 Feb 2018
    Set App = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    ' 20 Feb 2018
    Debug.Print "NewWorkbook"
    If IsNewWb Then ShowDocSpecs "New"
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    ' 20 Feb 2018

    Dim Ff As XlFileFormat

    On Error Resume Next
    Ff = Wb.FileFormat

    Debug.Print "WorkbookOpen: FileFormat = "; Ff
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Ff And (Len(Wb.Path) = 0) Then          ' see "Peculiarities"
        ShowDocSpecs "Open"
    End If
    CloseBlankWb
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' 20 Feb 2018
    Debug.Print "BeforeClose: Workbooks.Count = "; Workbooks.Count
    IsNewWb = CBool(Workbooks.Count)           ' see "Peculiarities"
End Sub

Private Sub ShowDocSpecs(CalledBy As String)
    ' 20 Feb 2018
    ' always return True

    Dim FrmSpecs As DocSpecs

'    Set FrmSpecs = New DocSpecs
    MsgBox "Show WbSpecs: Called by " & CalledBy

    IsNewWb = True
End Sub

Private Sub CloseBlankWb()
    ' 20 Feb 2018

    Dim Wb As Workbook

    For Each Wb In Workbooks
        With Wb
            If Application.CountA(.Sheets(1).Cells) = 0 And _
               .Path = "" Then Debug.Print "Closing blank": .Close
        End With
    Next Wb
End Sub
```